# Why does the Pandas pivot_table function sum some values correctly while missing others

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have had an issue with a pivot_table code reading multiple values correctly while reading others incorrectly. Has anyone ever run into issue similar to this? I initated a groupby function early on so that I could make sure the summed values were summing correctly. They were, and then the pivot threw everything out of whack.

I've tried multiple techniques (groupby before pivot, loc), but none address the sum issue

```
mask= (I_FY['Commodity'] == 'Urea (Solid)') | (I_FY['Commodity'] == 
'Other Urea')

df=I_FY.loc[mask]
UreaImp= df

UreaImp.groupby(['Year', 'FY','Month','Country']) 
['Volume'].sum().unstack()

UreaImp= pd.pivot_table(UreaImp, values = 'Volume', index=['Year', 'FY', 
'Month'], columns = ['Country']).reset_index()
```

Here's a sampling of the data before the pivot

```
FY        Month   Country      Year   Volume
2018/19        1  Belgium      2019       1
2018/19        1  Canada       2019       1
```

Here's an expression of the data issue after the pivot

```
Year    FY        Month   Canada    Belgium
2019    2018/19     1      .5          1
```

Comment: the default aggregation is `mean`

Comment: "function, list of functions, dict, *default numpy.mean*" You need to `aggfunc='sum'` parameter to your pivot_table method.